# What if you cant invoke [super init] first

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to subclass `UIPopoverController` and give IT the proper responsibility of determining what kind of UIViewController (contentViewController) to create and present rather than horribly cluttering the popover's calling code with that responsibility.  But I'm running into several issues.

According to Apple documentation, there is never a valid reason to do anything before first calling.

```
if (self = [super init])
```

So I tried that, thinking I could then simply set the `contentViewController` property later in the method when my code examined the data I pass in and makes the decision about which UIViewController to create and prsent, but calling `[super init]` blows up with an error telling me I have to call the other initializer.

```
[super initWithContentViewController:...]
```

So my problem is illustrated below.  I can't use the first lines of my custom initializer to make the decision and THEN call super when the call to super is supposed to be the very first call and according to apple, there's never a good reason to not have it be the first call.

```
initWithData:(MyDataObject*)data
   // examine data object and determine what kind
   // of UIViewController to create and present
   //
   // [super initWithContentViewController:myDecidedContentViewController
```

What to do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/index.html) on `UIPopoverController`:

> When initializing an instance of this class, you must specify the view controller that provides the content for the popover.

`UIPopoverController` doesn't have any content of it's own, it needs another `UIViewController` that renders the stuff you actually want to present. Any subclass of `UIViewController` would suffice, as long as it doesn't conflict with the popover controller.

For example you can use a custom designed controller from a `Storyboard` or a `XIB`, or a programatically instantiated `UIViewController`. You're not limited to these two, though. Subclassing `UIPopoverController` won't help, as the subclass still needs a content controller.

Now, subclassing `UIPopoverController` and implementing the logic for creating the content controller within that class, is a violation of the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) as you'll mix the responsibilities for the popover class. Currently the `UIPopoverController` has one and good responsibility - to display view controllers in a popover, you're only burdening it if you also make it responsible of creating content controllers.

My recommendation would be to create a `MyPopoverFactory` class that have methods that will create both the popover and its content controller. For example:

```
- (UIPopoverController*)popoverForSomething
```

Comment: It's not the responsibility of `UIPopoverController` to create other controllers, its responsibility is to display them in a special way. You're mixing  responsibilities you you want it also to create controllers. I'd suggest creating another class that will create both the popover and the content controller, will update my answer with more details.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable alternative, though it would create a lot more code.  Now that I think about it, it does seem I'm breaking the MVC responsibility (Massive View Controller) by putting data decisions inside a view instead of the Massive View Controller or some class it references.

Comment: `Massive View Controller` - that's an interesting term :)

Comment: Yes, the MVVM design principle is coming into popularity because the view controller becomes a ginormous bloated heap of code that does way too much, as well as being the improper place to do certain things.  Read about MVVM for iOS and you'll see 'massive view controller' referenced a lot.

Comment: Yeah, `MVC` tends to generate huge controllers, however as the UIKit is based on this pattern it's kinda hard to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know, whether this helps, because I do not really understand, what decision you have to make. But the general patten you can use in such a situation (it is similiar to a class cluster) is to have another creator. (You can do that with `-init…`, too, but this is inconvenient. If you need it, let me know.)

```
+ (instancetype)myPopUpControllerForData:(id)data
{
    // make the decision on data
    Class contentViewControllerType;
    contenViweControllerType = …; 

    // After that create the instance of the content view controller
    contentViewController = [[ContentViewControllerType alloc] init…];

    // init… is the first message after alloction
    self = [[self alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController];

    return self;
}
```

The documentation only requires that `-init…` is the first message to the allocated instance. That does not mean that you lose the liberty to run code that is *not* related to *that instance*.

Comment: While your answer is technically correct and doable, it was my improper premise that was faulty, and led to your answer.  I shouldn't be trying to put data decision code inside views... that's a no no in MVC type of code.  I'm still suffering from .NET indoctorination and haven't fully absorbed the MVC principles yet.

Comment: It depends on what `data` is. If it is a common data type like `NSArray`, `NSSet` and so on, I would not reject your idea. These types are a general "background" to the MVC stack. Beside this you make your decision for a *controller* depending on data type. I would not say that this is a bad design. (And of course a strict appliance of the MVC can hurt. There are several classes in Cocoa, which are not belonging to exactly one layer.)